# One of my co-authors is an "IEEE Life Member" can I add this to my IEEE transaction manuscript?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, ieee

I just finished a Transaction Manuscript, and one of the co-authors is a "Life member IEEE". Initially, I inserted "Senior Member IEEE" just after his name in the manuscript, but he pointed out to me that he is a life member. So my question is, can I remove the "Senior Member IEEE" and insert "Life Member IEEE" even though I haven't seen any paper having "Life member IEEE"?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that your coauthor is lying to you?

Comment: Search for the latest papers by Professor Anthony Ephremides.  You will see he is a 'Life Fellow, IEEE' or 'Life Member, IEEE'

Comment: @JeffE no, I have no feeling he is lying, he is my co-mentor, and up till now, I never knew you could add that in a paper. I thought after Senior Member, then next thing that goes into the paper is Fellow. But with Prof. Santa Claus' comment, I can see that it is possible to put that on a paper.

Answer (score 1):

Being a new graduate student, I never knew that you could add "life*" to the paper. I felt you can only add member, senior member, follow. After googling, for a while, I found out that one can add life member, life fellow, or life senior member to an author's name.